# Issue with sending array of complex objects to MVC cotroller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, arrays, controller

using fiddler here is the posted data:

```
first.Id=1&first.Value=This+is+my+first+name.&second.Id=2&second.Value=The+second+one.
```

on the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Set(EditSettings[] settings)
{
   //the settings is always null
}
```

i have tried a lot of questions here at SO but none of them worked!

**since i had just two settings i managed to seperate the parameters and use a falttened object in my ajax post request.**

now my question is what type of string should be passed to the model binder instead of my initial string? what should be changed there since there is no "first" or "second" parameter names?

Comment: Please post the view code as well.

Comment: I'm not sure if this works with an array as well, but if you take in a `List<EditSettings> settings` parameter for your controller, then the model binder can bind to this list if it receives POST data in the format of `first[0].Id=1&second[1].Id=2` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not access these values with array in the controller action , because they haven't sent with an index.u can do the following to send data as array

```
$.ajax({
 url="Url For Action",
data = { data[0].Id : "0" ,  data[0].Value : "This is my first name" , data[1].Id : "1" ,  data[1].Value : "This is my second one"};
});
public void Set([DataBind(Prefix="data")] EditSettings[] settings)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are posting the query string instead of JSON. If I were you, I would be use JSON.stringify and it will be something like this:

```
var settings= new Array();
settings.push({ "id": "1", "value": "This+is+my+first+name." });
```

Then in your JQuery ajax call do the following:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'You URL',
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: "json",
        traditional: true,
        data: { 
            settings: JSON.stringify(settings),          
        },
        success: function () { window.alert('success'); },
        error: function (event, request, settings) {  
            window.alert('AjaxError' + ' : ' + settings); },
        timeout: 20000
});
```